# Wordpress posts are not showing at external page of website

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

I am just working on a website...Besides..I want to put a page as Iframe and want to show the a wordpress post in that page..

the problem is that it is not showing anything...when the code get executed..can you please look at it that what is going wrong?

Here is link to the page as: http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-content/themes/universal/content/register.php

here is My Iframe page code :

```
<?php 
require('http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/universal/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Register Page</title>
<link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.sb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">.dpmaxz_hidden {visibility: hidden;}#dpmaxz_root {-webkit-user-select: none; display: inline-block; z-index: 2147483647;margin: 0;padding: 0;}#dpmaxz_gui {-webkit-user-select: none; position: static; margin: 0;padding: 0;cursor: default;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg {display: block;position: absolute;cursor: default;margin: -25px 0 0 -32px;width: 50px;height: 24px;background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_fbishield {float: left;margin: -10px 0 0 3px;padding: 0;width: 29px;height: 37px;background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainimg.png) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_fbiauthok {background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainimg_ok.png) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_fbiauthno {background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainimg_no.png) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_fbixchg {background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainxchg.png) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_menuact {background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainmact.png) no-repeat;}#dpmaxz_root .dpmaxz_mainbkg .dpmaxz_fbiadd {height: 16px;width: 15px;float: right;background: transparent url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/mainadd.png) no-repeat;margin: 0 -16px 0 0;}#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus {position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; }.dpmaxz_menusrel {position: relative; }#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus ul {position: absolute; left: 0;top: 22px; list-style: none;white-space: nowrap;border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,245,255) 73%, white 100%);box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px -3px #605F70;font-family: 'Segoe UI',Verdana,Arial;font-style: normal;font-size: 1em;padding: 3px 3px;margin: 2px 4px 2px 4px;}#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus ul li {text-decoration: none;text-align: left;margin: 0; padding: 0;}#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus ul li:hover {border: 1px solid #aecff7;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;background-color: #edf1f6;margin: -1px;}#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus .dpmaxz_menurow {position: relative;color: black;height: 22px;float: none; }#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus .dpmaxz_menurow span {display: inline-block !important;  }#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus .dpmaxz_menurowicon {display: inline-block;width: 26px;height: 22px;position: relative;vertical-align: top;border-right: 1px solid #e2e3e3;font-size: 12px; color: black; }#dpmaxz_gui .dpmaxz_menus .dpmaxz_menurowtext {display: inline-block;border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;padding: 0 4px;font: normal 1em 'Segoe UI',Verdana,Arial; font-size: 12px;height: 22px;vertical-align: middle;}.dpmaxz_highlight {-webkit-border-image: url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/highlighter.png) 5 9 8 6 repeat;border-image: url(chrome-extension://ncffjdbbodifgldkcbhmiiljfcnbgjab/images/highlighter.png) 5 9 8 6 repeat;}</style>

<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<?php   $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=116"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;   ?> 

</body></html>
```

Comment: No...reply till now...

Comment: Try `require('../universal/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: or try `$parse_uri = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$wp_load = $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-blog-header.php';
require( $wp_load );`

Comment: Now...getting error...that directory is not found..

Comment: Thanks...it worked...the second one....! Post it as answer..and I will select answer and you will get reputation...please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$parse_uri = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$wp_load = $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-blog-header.php';
require( $wp_load );
```